# delete the js code that is still actively running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

js code keeps running even if element is removed from page.
first difficulty when coding with `react-js`. because the page is not reloaded so the initial script is still running, like `setInterval,websocket,etc` code. simple example below element has been removed but still running. not effective if i have to create with global variable

```html
<button onclick="createNewJsCode()">create new js</button>
<button onclick="removeJsCode()">remove js</button>
<script>
  let id = ''
  function createNewJsCode(){
    let s = document.createElement('script')
    let code = 'setInterval(`console.log(new Date())`,500)'
    s.id = (id = crypto.randomUUID())
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }
  function removeJsCode(){
    document.getElementById(id).remove()
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve, and what security problem you're worried about? Remember that **all** JS and HTML is visible to the end user, and can be trivially traced through with the debugging tools built into all popular browsers.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve, but indeed: removing a script tag will not halt JavaScript execution. If you're dealing with security concerns in client-side code, then you have a security hole to begin with, regardless of how you execute it.

Comment: Were is the React code here, normally things like `setInterval` etc can be removed on component  unmount.

Comment: The correct way to kill a running timer interval in plain JS (not sure if react has anything different), would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval

Comment: @Keith Yes. i want that answer. what do I have to do? what code should i look for?

Comment: @IMSoP I consider the webpack/react compiler as a solution for securing assets instead of having to create global variables

Comment: The connection between webpack, react, global variables, and the code you've shown is a complete mystery to me, and I can't think of any way it would "secure assets". It's all still code running in the browser, completely under control of the user of that browser.

Comment: And you clearly don't understand the first thing about web application security.

Comment: The best that tools like `terser` or `minify.js` can do is obfuscate, and security through obscurity is no security at all.

Comment: like in my profile. I really like blurring. like obfuscator.io, preemptive,jsdefender,jsscrambler.etc. unique low-level disguises such as packer, jsF*ck, jjencode, obfuscation malware, etc. but terser is the first step of obfuscate. terser->obfuscate->(safer???). No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen as this is a React question, below is an example of using a `setInterval` inside a React Component.  If your using some form of React Router the below code will also correctly unmount / mount etc.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Page() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(() => {
       console.log(new Date());
       setCounter(c => c +1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log('umount');
      clearInterval(i);
    }
  }, []);
  return <div>
    This is a page, and when unmounted will end the setInterval. <br/>Counter: {counter}, time: {new Date().toLocaleString()}<br/> Check console you will also see console logging of datetime finishes.
  </div>
}

function OtherInfo() {
  return <div>
    Notice how the timer stopped inside the console.  <br/>  If you click Show Page the component will be mounted again, this is kind of the basis of how React Router works in a Single Page Application (SPA).
  </div>
}

function App() {
  const [pageVis, setPageVis] = useState(true);
  return <div>
    {pageVis && <Page/>}
    {!pageVis && <OtherInfo/>}
    <hr/>
    {pageVis && <button onClick={() => setPageVis(false)}>Unmount Page</button>}
    {!pageVis && <button onClick={() => setPageVis(true)}>Show Page</button>}
  </div>
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#mount'));
root.render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove the `<script>` node, you have to do a little more specific cleanup.

`setInterval` returns an interval ID that you can pass to `clearInterval` to stop it.

Generally, I'd say your code does not make a whole lot of sense in a React context, but in your case you could do something like this:

```html
<button onclick="createNewJsCode()">create new js</button>
<button onclick="removeJsCode()">remove js</button>
<script>
  let id;
  let intervalId;
  function createNewJsCode(){
    let s = document.createElement('script')
    let code = 'intervalId = setInterval(`console.log(new Date())`,500)'
    s.id = (id = crypto.randomUUID())
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }
  function removeJsCode(){
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    document.getElementById(id).remove()
  }
</script>
```